# Como bloquear 2 usuarios na mesma tela - JAVA

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

Preciso bloquear o acesso de 2 pessoas em uma mesma tela, exemplo, duas pessoas tentam acessar o cadastro de um determinado produto, a segunda pessoa que tentar entrar deve receber um aviso que alguém esta acessando este cadastro.
Alguem teria alguma ideia?
Trabalho com java, jsf, primefaces e hibernate.

Comment: coloca um campo "bloqueado" no banco e quando o produto for acessado altera esse campo para true e quando sair para false.
E faz as tratativas para só permitir o acesso se o campo estiver false

Comment: Amigo até fiz isso mais encontrei alguns problemas, exemplo, a pessoa entrou e fechou o navegador, o status ficou como bloqueado.

Comment: Então você faz um javascript fazendo ping por ajax dizendo "ei cara, eu ainda estou aqui". Depois de um tempo sem receber esses pings, é porque a pessoa que está na tela foi embora. Se ela voltar, o servidor responde "já era cara, demorou demais, perdeu".

Comment: hmm entendi. Não dá para colocar um temporizador talvez?

Comment: Seria uma boa ideia essa do temporizador com ping, vou dar uma pesquisada pois sou meio analfabeto em javaScript

Comment: Mas vc precisa bloquear para edição ou para visualização? Se for para edição, então precisa de um controle mais refinado. Se for apenas para visualização, poderia implementar um websocket para ver quem está acessando a tela (Acho que seria melhor que o ping).